# Simulate mouse click using PostMessage

Tags: c#, click, postmessage, simulate

More recently, simulating a click using PostMessage has begun to activate the window. Previously, this was not and the click was performed in an inactive window without focus.

```
int coords = (y << 16) + x;
IntPtr lParam = new IntPtr(coords);
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const Int32 WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
const Int32 WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
```

Comment: Ever since Windows Vista one should not rely on posting messages via low-level message pump to other apps in the hope of controlling them since such actions can be blocked.  You might want to consider using Microsoft _UI Automation_ instead.   Though originally for testing applications, it can be used for remote control

Comment: See [AutomationElement.GetClickablePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.getclickablepoint). The AutomationElement can be a Window or any child element that can be clicked. But see the final note there. Anyway, it depends on what action you want to perform on a specific element (Window\child Control) type. Different elements implement different Patterns that can activate different actions.